# Jira links missing in Hudson

Tags: svn, hudson, jira

I'm trying to integrate Hudson CI with Jira. I'm using Hudson 2.1.0 and Jira 4.3.614. I've set up Hudson according to page http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/JIRA+Plugin. Jira has *Accept remote API calls* option set to ON. Hudson has proper URL configured, *Supports Wiki Notation* and *Record Scm changes* options are checked on, issue pattern is set to *AB-([0-9])+*, user name and passwords are also set to valid Jira user. In my hudson's job configuration I've got option *Update relevant JIRA issues* marked. Problem is that whenever there is svn check-in and build is triggered in hudson's change log I can see only text like: "2233. AB-353 Data issue in Orders Pending in Dev Database", but *AB-353* is normal text, not link to Jira. Anybody has any idea why I don't have proper links for Jira issues? Am I missing some Jira or Hudson configuration setting? Maybe some protocol or plugin missing?

Thanks,
Roman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was with my regular expression. I had it as:

AB-([0-9])+

while Jira's plugin expected something like this:

(AB-[0-9]+)

with brackets around the whole expression.